# Firefox "Exited full-screen because windowed plugin was focused"

Tags: javascript, actionscript-3, flash, firefox, fullscreen

Firefox exits full-screen mode after clicking on Flash.
You can test it on our Facebook game: https://apps.facebook.com/upogame/ffbug.html

Firefox log:

```
Exited full-screen because windowed plugin was focused.
```

Javascript code for fullscreen:

```
if ((document.fullScreenElement && document.fullScreenElement !== null) ||    // alternative standard method
        (!document.mozFullScreen && !document.webkitIsFullScreen)) {
    if (document.documentElement.requestFullScreen) {
        document.documentElement.requestFullScreen();
    } else if (document.documentElement.mozRequestFullScreen) {
        document.documentElement.mozRequestFullScreen();
    } else if (document.documentElement.webkitRequestFullScreen) {
        document.documentElement.webkitRequestFullScreen(Element.ALLOW_KEYBOARD_INPUT);
    }

} else {
    if (document.cancelFullScreen) {
        document.cancelFullScreen();
    } else if (document.mozCancelFullScreen) {
        document.mozCancelFullScreen();
    } else if (document.webkitCancelFullScreen) {
        document.webkitCancelFullScreen();
    }
}
```

Embed code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var swfVersionStr = "18.0.0";
    var xiSwfUrlStr = "playerProductInstall.swf";
    var flashvars = {};
    var params = {};
    params.quality = "high";
    params.bgcolor = "#B0E0FF";
    params.allowscriptaccess = "sameDomain";
    params.allowfullscreen = "true";
    params.allowFullScreenInteractive = "true";
    params.wmode = "direct";
    var attributes = {};
    attributes.id = "OOPPO";
    attributes.name = "OOPPO";
    attributes.align = "middle";
    swfobject.embedSWF(
        "secure_Ooppo.swf?"+"19", "flashContent",
        "100%", "100%",
        swfVersionStr, xiSwfUrlStr, 
        flashvars, params, attributes);
    swfobject.createCSS("#flashContent", "display:block; text-align:left;");
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Fullscreen was disabled on Firefox for windowed plugins to prevent security issues like phishing. [This bug](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=684618) was reported and fixed for this reason.

In your case, I believe you would need to set either params.wmode = 'transparent' or params.wmode = 'opaque' on the swfobject for fullscreen to work on Firefox.

Comment: Thanks @ami91, but in my case I need to use wmode direct. I use Starling framework. Starling is based on Stage 3D. Your answer is right but not solution for me. I solved it by using Full-screen Interactive on FF and requestFullScreen() on Chrome. Full-screen Interactive was not working on Chrome.

Comment: I think, I should write the code that solved for me this problem and mark it as answer? Yes? I'm not experienced user of SO.

Comment: @Ghelle Yes, please add your solution and mark it as the answer. I would love to see how you solved it and it will be helpful for others who stumble upon this question. It will help improve your SO reputation too ;)